# Snakemake - rule that downloads data

Tags: download, snakemake

I am having some trouble implementing a pipeline in which the first step is downloading the data from some server. As far as I understand, all rules must have inputs which are files. However, in my case the "input" is an ID string given to a script which accesses the server and downloads the data.
I am aware of the [remote files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html) option in snakemake, but the server I am downloading from ([ENA](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena)) is not on that list. Moreover, I am using a script which calls aspera in order to improve download speed.
Any ideas of how such a scenario can be implemented in snakemake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules actually do not need an input field, so sth like this is possible:

```
rule download:
    output:
        "downloads/{sample}.fa"
    shell:
        "ascp ftp:/url_here+{wildcards.sample}"
```