# snakemake envvars are not passed to cluster execution (snakemake throws an error)

Tags: python, snakemake

I define [envvars](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html?highlight=envvars#environment-variables) to be passed to a shell script.

```
envvars:
    "PASS"
```

If I forget to specify them in the shell, the dry-run using `snakemake -n` will remind me to set it. Execution works just fine on my local machine, but I do not manage to pass the envvars to my cluster environment. I run into the following snakemake error after my cluster execution although I set the environment variable. The job is never launched due to the snakemake error.

```
WorkflowError in line 10 of /home/workflows/Snakefile:
The following environment variables are requested by the workflow but undefined. Please make sure that they are correctly defined before running Snakemake:
PASS
  File "/home/workflows/Snakefile", line 11, in <module>
```

after executing snakemake using `snakemake --jobs 2 --latency-wait 30 --cluster "qsub ..."`. Explicitly specifying the envvars did not help: `snakemake --jobs 2 --latency-wait 30 --cluster "qsub ..." --envvars PASS`.

Is snakemake executed again in a different shell other the initial snakemake client shell?

Comment: [ClusterExecutor](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/executors.html#ClusterExecutor) states that snakemake is invoked again, but then without the `envvars` from the main process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add [flag `-V` to qsub](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm) to make environment variables available to qsub jobs.

```
-V    Declares that all environment variables in the qsub commands environment are to be exported to the batch job.
```

Comment: thank you very much! I wasn't aware of that option...