# Does snakemake support none file Input?

Tags: snakemake

I get a `MissingInputException` when I run the following rule:

```
configfile: "Configs.yaml"

rule download_data_from_ZFIN:
    input:
        anatomy_item = config["ZFIN_url"]["anatomy_item"],
        xpat_stage_anatomy = config["ZFIN_url"]["xpat_stage_anatomy"],
        xpat_fish = config["ZFIN_url"]["xpat_fish"],
        anatomy_synonyms = config["ZFIN_url"]["anatomy_synonyms"]
    output:
        anatomy_item = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), config["download_data_from_ZFIN"]["dir"], "anatomy_item.tsv"),
        xpat_stage_anatomy = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), config["download_data_from_ZFIN"]["dir"], "xpat_stage_anatomy.tsv"),
        xpat_fish = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), config["download_data_from_ZFIN"]["dir"], "xpat_fish.tsv"),
        anatomy_synonyms = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), config["download_data_from_ZFIN"]["dir"], "anatomy_synonyms.tsv")
    shell:
        "wget -O {output.anatomy_item} {input.anatomy_item};" \
        "wget -O {output.anatomy_synonyms} {input.anatomy_synonyms};" \
        "wget -O {output.xpat_stage_anatomy} {input.xpat_stage_anatomy};" \
        "wget -O {output.xpat_fish} {input.xpat_fish};"
```

And this is the content of my `configs.yaml` file:

```
ZFIN_url:
  # Zebrafish Anatomy Term
  anatomy_item: "https://zfin.org/downloads/file/anatomy_item.txt"
  # Zebrafish Gene Expression by Stage and Anatomy Term
  xpat_stage_anatomy: "https://zfin.org/downloads/file/xpat_stage_anatomy.txt"
  # ZFIN Genes with Expression Assay Records
  xpat_fish: "https://zfin.org/downloads/file/xpat_fish.txt"
  # Zebrafish Anatomy Term Synonyms
  anatomy_synonyms: "https://zfin.org/downloads/file/anatomy_synonyms.txt"

download_data_from_ZFIN:
  dir: ZFIN_data
```

The error message is:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 10 of /home/zhangdong/works/NGS/coevolution/snakemake/coevolution.rule:
Missing input files for rule download_data_from_ZFIN:
https://zfin.org/downloads/file/anatomy_item.txt
```

I want to make sure that if this exception is caused by none file input for the `input` rule?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053035/snakemake-rule-that-downloads-data. The file requires no input, so listing urls are required files on your computer is wrong. You could put those urls as params instead of input

Comment: Hi Maarten-vd-Sande, thank you very much, as you suggested, it worked when I remove the `input` part.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also use [remote files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html#read-only-web-http-s) as input so you may avoid rule `download_data_from_ZFIN` altogether. E.g.:

```
from snakemake.remote.HTTP import RemoteProvider as HTTPRemoteProvider

HTTP = HTTPRemoteProvider()

rule all:
    input:
        'output.txt',

rule one:
    input:
        # Some file from the web
        x= HTTP.remote('https://plasmodb.org/common/downloads/release-49/PbergheiANKA/txt/PlasmoDB-49_PbergheiANKA_CodonUsage.txt', keep_local=True)
    output:
        'output.txt',
    shell:
        r"""
        # Do something with the remote file
        head {input.x} > {output}
        """
```

The remote file will be downloaded and stored locally under `plasmodb.org/common/.../PlasmoDB-49_PbergheiANKA_CodonUsage.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks @dariober, I tried the follwing code and it worked,

```
import os
from snakemake.remote.HTTP import RemoteProvider as HTTPRemoteProvider
configfile: "Configs.yaml"

HTTP = HTTPRemoteProvider()

rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),config["download_data_from_ZFIN"]["dir"],"{item}.tsv"),
            item=list(config["ZFIN_url"].keys()))

rule download_data_from_ZFIN:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: HTTP.remote(config["ZFIN_url"][wildcards.item], keep_local=True)
    output:
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(),config["download_data_from_ZFIN"]["dir"],"{item}.tsv")
    threads:
        1
    shell:
        "mv {input} > {output}"
```

Such code is more snakemake-like, but I have two further questions:

1. Is there a way to specify the output file name for the downloading? Now I use the `mv` command to achieve that.
2. Does this `remote files` function support parallel works? I tried the above code together with `--cores 6`, but it still download the file one by one.